# Switch 2 list in SelectInput on radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

How to switch 2 list (fooChoices1 and fooChoices2) into a selectInput depending on a radioButton selection ?

I wish a global file with the 2 list

Also, is it possible to block character entry in the SelectInput to have only the list choice (because I drive a SQL query on this selection) ?

Thank you for your help

Here is my UI.R :

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Measures"),
sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons("base", "Select DB", 
  c("base1"="base-1","base2"="base-2")),

  selectInput("cible", "Select le test:", 
                       choices = fooChoices, selected = "ALL"),
),


mainPanel(

 plotlyOutput("plot")
   ))
```

Here my global.R file :

```
fooChoices1<-c("ALL" = "00 00%",
                         "SPEC2" = "00 00297",
                         "SPEC3" = "00 00323",
                         "SPEC4" = "00 00362",
                         "SPEC5" = "00 00366",
                         "SPEC6" = "00 00399"
          )

fooChoices2<-c("ALL" = "00 00%",
                         "SPEC2" = "00 00297",
                         "SPEC3" = "00 00323",
                         "SPEC4" = "00 00362",
                         "SPEC5" = "00 00366",
                         "SPEC6" = "00 00399")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the switch with an `observeEvent` in your server function

```
observeEvent({
    input$base
  },
  {
    if(input$base == "base-1"){
      updateSelectInput(
        inputId = "cible",
        choices = fooChoices1, 
        selected = "ALL"
      )
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(
        inputId = "cible",
        choices = fooChoices2, 
        selected = "ALL"
      )
    }
  })
```

About your second Question: if I understand you right it is actually not necessary to block the text input - this is only a search tool when you have a lot of options - the user is still limited to the choices defined in the parameter choices.

Answer (score 0):

I try with observeEvent but it doesn't work and Shiny quit

I find this :

```
output$cible <- renderUI({

 if(input$base == "base-1")
selectInput("cible", "Select test:", 
                       choices = fooChoices1)
else 
  selectInput("cible", "Select test:", 
             choices = fooChoices2)



 })
```

with in UI.R

```
   uiOutput("cible"),
```